# Song always starts at the beginning

Tags: rendering

Currently whenever I render an audio clip it always starts from the beginning regardless of where I am in the audio clip. It's obviously a bug, but any idea on how to fix this?

Comment: probably a silly question but have you got your start and end frames set in the render settings where you want them? By default it'll be on frame 1 so will render the start of your audio file. Without seeing a blend file though it's hard to say. I've just done a test render on an animation i have and the audio starts from the frame i have selected.

Comment: Yes, I have changed the start and end points. I've even cut the audio clip down and it still starts it from the beginning.

Comment: strange, like I say i just did a quick test on 50 frames in the middle of an animation and the audio was as expected. I presume you're on the latest version of blender? Can you post a blend file?

Comment: Let me make sure I'm up to date on the latest version first in case it was a bug they fixed. I'll post a blender file after if that doesn't work.

Comment: So that didn't help. Although I understand a bit better what is happening. It's not that it's starting at the beginning. It's that if I start anywhere other than the beginning it plays much less of the file audio file than my video file. When started from the beginning it works just fine. Just that from any other point the audio file is significantly farther behind the video file. Also I don't know how to post my blend file here.

Comment: If you upload it to something like www.wetransfer.com it'll send you a link which you can post here. Just make sure to pack the blend file

Comment: https://www.wetransfer.com/downloads/49a41fb463f426f9544095a77f4dd55320160218012601/d74845ede1348b7be16a704b593e790c20160218012601/ee0736

Comment: I don't think you packed the file? Make sure and go to "File > External Data > Pack All Into Blend" at the moment it's just an empty file

Comment: I just checked the link and it opened just fine for me. It was saved on a windows 10 computer 64 bit if that changes anything.

Comment: On the bright side at least the new version of blender renders noticeably faster.

Comment: i had this issue recently , as a quick workaround I pack the sound clip in the VSE and then unpack it.

Answer (score 1):

[image]

You should turn the options: "AV-sync" and "Audio Scrubbing" on. It should help fix your problem.

Comment: Both were already selected.